# NLog Structured logging converts all values to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

We are using the NLog integration for asp.net core to manage our logs. We need to generate a JSON log containing the response time (duration).

The code below:

```
logger.LogInformation("Duration {duration}", 122);
```

With the following configuration:

```xml
<target name="aws" type="Debugger">
  <layout type="JsonLayout">
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
    <attribute name="msg" layout="${message}" />
    <attribute name="err" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
    <attribute name="meta" encode="false">
      <layout type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="requestId" layout="${aspnet-traceidentifier}" />
        <attribute name="user" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
        <attribute name="agent" layout="${aspnet-request-useragent}" />
        <attribute name="method" layout="${aspnet-request-method}" />
        <attribute name="url" layout="${aspnet-request-url:IncludeHost=true:IncludePort=true:IncludeQueryString=true}" />
        <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <attribute name="duration" layout="${event-properties:duration}" />
      </layout>
    </attribute>
  </layout>
</target>
```

always generate an output that looks like this:

```
{
    "level": "Info",
    "msg": "Duration 122",
    "meta": {
        "requestId": "0HLKTC2E2B3KL:00000002",
        "agent": "PostmanRuntime\/7.6.0",
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "http:\/\/localhost:20000\/api\/v1\/oauth\/token",
        "logger": "TEC.CoreApi.Application.Features.Authentication.OAuthController",
        "duration": "122"
    }
}
```

As you can see the duration became a string and that prevents us from using our log parser (CloudWatch Logs). I absolutely need to get the duration as a numeric value.

Any idea on how I could work around this issue?

Thx
Sebastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```xml
<attribute name="duration" layout="${event-properties:duration}"/>
```

with

```xml
<attribute name="duration" layout="${event-properties:duration}" encode="false"/>
```